# Supabase: how to update a column with a Reference attribute

Tags: c#, postgresql, supabase

I'm having problems updating a column of my model with the `Reference` attribute.

Please find below my model:

```cs
[Table("Incidents")]
public class Incident : BaseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey("id", false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Reference(typeof(User), ReferenceAttribute.JoinType.Left, columnName: "assigned_to")]
    public User? AssignedTo { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class User : BaseModel
{
   [PrimaryKey("id", false)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column("first_name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [Column("last_name")]
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The table `Incidents` on the database contains a column with the name `assigned_to` which is an `integer` and a foreign key to the `Users` table.

When I execute the following code, the column `assigned_to` isn't updated.

```cs
var incident = await client
                              .From<Incident>()
                              .Where(incident => incident.Id == update.Id)
                              .Set(incident => incident.Title, update.Title)
                              .Set(incident => incident.Description, update.Description)
                              .Set(incident => incident.Priority, update.Priority)
                              .Set(incident => incident.AssignedTo, update.AssignedTo)
                              .Update();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the issue, I found that the framework doesn't do the conversion automatically. Shame!

In case someone has the same problem, a possible solution is:

- Add a new property to the Incident class, for example, AssignedToUserInformation.
- Remove the Reference attribute from the current AssignedTo field and replace it with the [Column("assigned_to")]
- Add the Reference attribute to the recently created attribute AssignedToUserInformation: [Reference(typeof(User), ReferenceAttribute.JoinType.Left)]

This should work now because the Reference attributes are ignored when the Update() method is executed.